# Sortable JS placeholder height issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this jQuery sortable UI placeholder height issue? (https://jsfiddle.net/jcbrown/jq2Low73/1/) This is a gallery list and for the 1st gallery item, the size will be bigger than the rest. I need the make sure it is responsive, so I cannot set a fix height or width on it.

The issue is when I try to move the 1st item, the height of the .uploadedimg_list will change (smaller than it should be). If you notice closely, the 2nd item should follow the height of the 1st item, but it didn't. I can't seem to make this work and I can't find the answer on Google either. Kindly advice. :)

```
<ul class="list-unstyled uploadedimg_list">
  <li class="uploadedimg_item">
    <div>
      <span class="image-wrapper"><img src=
                "http://sdtimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/0827.sdt-blog-google.png"></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>



$('.uploadedimg_list').sortable({
  helper: 'clone',
  start: function(e, ui){
    ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.